# PuTTY - no recent connections in Windows 10 version 1607

Tags: windows, windows-10, putty

In previous installation of Windows, when I right clicked on PuTTY I got a list of the last ten connections that was very useful. But now after a fresh install of Windows 10 version 1607 it's not there any more - I get only Tasks as shown in the screen shot (those were not available in my previous installation). Is it Windows settings (and could it be updated somewhere - for example privacy or something like this) or maybe this is PuTTY/Windows bug?

**EDIT** I'm not interested in workaround to create separate link for each connection I have as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1009597/putty-taskbar-jump-list-broken-on-windows-10). I would rather want to have last x connections as it should work and worked in my previous Windows 10 installation

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: @Run5k In mentioned post there's only quite simple workaround for this to create shortcut for each connection and it's not the same as solving issue

Comment: That is understandable.  Just to double-check, you installed PuTTY 0.67 from the [MSI installer](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) and aren't running the portable version, correct?

Comment: @Run5k Yes, I've used putty-0.67-installer.msi to install